# How can I implement $http in Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am having problems defining my $http call in Typescript. Previously I was using .success and .error like this:

```
this.$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: self.ac.dataServer + url
        })
            .success((data: any, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: ng.IRequestConfig): void => {
                self.topics = angular.copy(data);
                self.topicsBase = angular.copy(data);
                this.$state.transitionTo('home.subjects.subject.admin.topics', {
                    subjectId: this.sus.subject.id
                });
            })
            .error((data, status, headers, config): void => {
                self.topics = null;
                self.topicsBase = null;
            })
            .finally((): void => {
            });
```

Now I changed to use .then:

```
 this.$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: self.ac.dataServer + url
        })
            .then(
            (response): any => {
                self.topics = angular.copy(response.data);
                self.topicsBase = angular.copy(response.data);
                this.$state.transitionTo('home.subjects.subject.admin.topics', {
                    subjectId: this.sus.subject.id
                });},
            (response): any => {
                self.topics = null;
                self.topicsBase = null;
            }
            );
```

But this gives me the following errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error TS2322  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ITopic[]'.
>   Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.    admin   C:\H\admin\admin\app\services\topicservice.ts   214
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  TS2322  Type '{}' is
>   not assignable to type
>   'ITopic[]'.   admin   C:\H\admin\admin\app\services\topicservice.ts   215

The errors come up on the lines where I am assigning an angular.copy(data) to self.topics and self.topicsBase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Argument of type `'(data: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<{}>, status: any, headers: any, config: any) => any'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'(response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<{}>) => any'`

You are passing a function that takes more arguments than what is returned by `$http()`.

## Fixed :

```
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: myURL
})
    .then((response): any => { },(): any => {});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sorry but I realized this after posting the question and just tried a quick edit while you were entering your answer. Now I fixed that but I have another problem.  The data coming back used to have a type of :any so it fitted well into self.topics and self.topicsBase.  Can you give me a suggestion how I could fix this now.

Comment: `Can you give me a suggestion how I could fix this now.` Specify the generic ... but might as well put a put annotation on `response`

Comment: If you don't mind can you give me an example of what you mean?  Are you suggesting one way would be to add <ITopic[]> before angular.copy? Also how could i do this with an annotation on response, that's the one i am really confused about. Thank you very much

Comment: `Also how could i do this with an annotation on response, that's the one i am really confused about` : e.g. : `.then((response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<{foo:string}>): any => { },(): any => {});`

Comment: I had some difficulties with the callback arguments but from what I see you answered this question correctly.  I will open up another question that's a bit more specific. Thanks